# Собрать в строке все строки имеющие кавычки RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

С сервера приходит строка:

```
let str = '(list "https:url1" "https:url2" "https:url3")';
```

Нужно собрать все url в один массив:

```
let regex = /"(.*?)"/g;
let fin = str.match(regex);
```

Но на выходе получается массив в двойных двойных кавычках:

```
[""https:url1"", ""https:url2"", ""https:url3""]
```

Можно стандартным способом избавиться от одних кавычек, чтобы было так?

```
  ["https:url1", "https:url2", "https:url3"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[...'(list "https:url1" "https:url2" "https:url3")'.matchAll(/"(.*?)"/g)].map(array => array[1])
```

или

```
(?<=")\S*?(?=")
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне важен Edge, а он пока MatchAll не поддерживает

Comment: @Marina обновил

Comment: О, да, через lookbehind, спасибо!

Comment: @Marina меня смущают двойные кавычки только, думаю как и одинарные вставить))

Comment: В ответе всегда двойные приходят)

Comment: @Marina, принял)

Comment: Вот так вроде работает и для одинарных )
/(?<=(\"|\'))\S*?(?=(\"|\'))/g

Comment: @Marina (?<=(['"]))\S*?(?=\1)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = '(list "https:url1" "https:url2" "https:url3")';

let reg = /"(.*?)"/g;

console.log(str.match(reg).map(elem => elem.replace(/"/g, '')));
```

Вот так, я думаю, можно решить.